# How to upload multiple Images to server - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm currently doing a mulitple images upload by using the **multi_image_picker: ^4.7.14** and trying to send it to the server with the help of **dio: ^3.0.10** MultipartRequest.

Tried doing it in two approchs

```
void uploadProduct() async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(Constant.postAdUrl);
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'};
    http.MultipartRequest request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.fields['adcover'] = coverImage;
    request.fields['ads_userfkid'] = userId;
    request.fields['ads_name'] = widget.title;
    request.fields['ads_description'] = widget.description;
    request.fields['ads_price'] = widget.price;
    request.fields['ads_subcatfkid'] = widget.subId;
    request.fields['ads_location'] = widget.location;
    List<MultipartFile> newList = new List<MultipartFile>();
    for(int i=0; i<images.length; i++){
      File imageFile = File(images[i].toString());
      var stream = new http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
      var length = await imageFile.length();
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('files[]', stream, length, filename:imageFile.path.split('/').last);
      newList.add(multipartFile);
    }
    request.files.addAll(newList);
    var response = await request.send();
    print(request.fields);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response);
      print("Image Uploaded");
    } else {
      print("Upload Failed");
    }
  }
```

Here I'm getting an error as **The argument type MultipartFile(where MultipartFile is defined in http-0.12.2) can't be assigned to the parameter type MultipartFile(where MultipartFile is defined in dio-3.0.10)**

And in the other way i did like this

```
void uploadProduct() async {
    print("Inside conversion");
    String postUrl = Constant.postAdUrl;
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'};
    try {
      var dio = new Dio();
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
        'files[]' : images,
        'adcover' : _image,
        'ads_subcatfkid' : widget.subId,
        'ads_userfkid' : userId,
        'ads_name' : widget.title,
        'ads_description' : widget.description,
        'ads_price' : widget.price,
        'ads_location' : widget.location,
      });
      Response resp = await dio.post(postUrl, data: formData, options: Options(headers: headers));
      if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
        print(resp.data);
      }
    } catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

But here none of the data is getting posted in the server

Answer (score 0):

This is because `MultipartFile` exists in both `dio` and `http` libraries. You have done everything right except for this line:
`List<MultipartFile> newList = new List<MultipartFile>();`
Change this line to:
`List<http.MultipartFile> newList = new List<http.MultipartFile>();`
and this should work. Because you must have imported `http` library with the alias `http`. That's why everywhere you have to write `http.ClassName` or `http.FunctionName`. That applies for `MultipartFile` also.

Comment: But now I'm getting an error as Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'Instance of 'Asset'' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: Now its an issue of how you are getting image paths. If `images` is a `List` of asset names. Then I suggest using `rootBundle` to get byte data from them.